# PHP, MySql adding a link to data from table

Tags: php, mysql

The problem I met is when I add a link, the link won't show up.

Here's my code

```
foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
     if ($k == "name") {   // name is table column
         $url = "<a href='http://127.0.0.1/People-Match/person.php'>".$v."</a>";
         echo $url;
     } else {
        echo $v;
     }
}
```

For the table format, I use below code

```
echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
echo "<tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Sex</th><th>Phone</th><th>Email</th><th>Address</th><th>Birth Date</th><th>Place of Birth</th></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {
     function __construct($it) {
         parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
     }

     function current() {
         return "<td style='width: 150px; border: 1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
     }

     function beginChildren() {
         echo "<tr>";
     }

     function endChildren() {
         echo "</tr>" . "\n";
     }
}
```

Comment: First glance, I see a missing } at the end of the section (closing the foreach statement) but that could be a copy error. Have you tried using any error_message displaying?

Comment: I don't have much experience in php, since it's a strange problem. I don't know where and how to add the error_message command.